# Data model with 3-level nesting with constrained middle-level

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I am looking for the appropriate data model for the following problem, using Postgres.  Is it possible without resorting to across-table constraints, or application-level checks?

The following entities are related in a nested 3-level hierarchy:

1. Group
2. SubGroup
3. Item

with these 3 constraints:

1. A SubGroup belongs to one Group
2. Items are many-to-many with Groups
3. An Item associated to a Group belongs to 0 or 1 SubGroups associated to that Group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- Group (GroupID) exists.
group {GroupID}
   PK {GroupID}

-- Sub-group (SubID) belongs to group (GroupID).
subgrp {SubID, GroupID}
    PK {SubID}
    SK {SubID, GroupID}  -- unique, (superkey needed for FK target)
   FK1 {GroupID} REFERENCES group {GroupID}

-- Item (ItemID) exists.
item {ItemID}
  PK {ItemID}

-- Item (ItemID) is associated with group (GroupID).
item_group {ItemID, GroupID}
        PK {ItemID, GroupID}
       FK1 {ItemID}  REFERENCES item  {ItemID}
       FK2 {GroupID} REFERENCES group {GroupID}

-- Item (ItemID) associated with group (GroupID) belongs to sub-group (SubID).
item_subgrp {ItemID, GroupID, SubID}
         PK {ItemID, GroupID}
        FK1 {ItemID, GroupID} REFERENCES item_group {ItemID, GroupID}
        FK2 {SubID, GroupID}  REFERENCES subgrp     {SubID, GroupID}
```

Notes:

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

PK = Primary Key
SK = Superkey (Unique)
AK = Alternate Key (Unique)
FK = Foreign Key
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks - having two two-column foreign keys was the trick.  I know this was a very specific problem, and appreciate your help.

It's possible the subgrp superkey of {SubID, GroupID} may not be strictly necessary, since the primary key of {SubID} does enforce uniqueness of {SubID, GroupID} already.

Comment: @UricSou, yes superkey `{SubID, GroupID}` is logically redundant, but SQL Foreign Key constraint requires unique index (constraint) for the reference.